# Front door can't access the KV certificate

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault, azure-front-door

I'm trying to add a custom certificate on the Azure Front Door from a key vault.

When the AKV has a network firewall enabled the AFD can't access the certificate even if the *Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall* is enabled and I have a valid AFD access policy to the key vault.

When I disable the network firewall, the AFD can access the certificate.. It appears that the whole problem is in the firewall section.

Am I missing something here ? Does anyone faced this problem before ?

Comment: AKV & AFD belong to the same subscription?

Comment: Yes they both are in the same subscription.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the problem is that we were using the portal for test, and that takes into account user access not AFD access.
So, if you apply this by using an arm template it should work, because the afd has the right access to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a custom certificate, please ensure that it is a part of **Microsoft Certificate authority** [list](https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/microsoft/IncludedCACertificateReportForMSFT).

If the certificate is not a part of that list, Firewall will block it as you have enabled this option "**_Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall**_"

If it is a part of that list, please check whether you have followed below steps to [create access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain-https#grant-azure-front-door-access-to-your-key-vault).

- Keyvault Account -> settings -> Access policies -> Add new -> Select principal (**ad0e1c7e-6d38-4ba4-9efd-0bc77ba9f037**) -> ***Microsoft.Azure.Frontdoor.*** ->Select.
- In both secret and certificate permissions ->Select Get -> Select Add -> Save.

For more **reference**, please find this link :

[Tutorial - Configure HTTPS on a custom domain for Azure Front Door | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain-https#tlsssl-certificates).

Comment: Yes, all the things mentionned above are already considered. 
The problem actually is coming from the KV firewall; When it is enabled the certificate doesn't appear in the secret section for the AFD, and when it's disabled ( all network ) the certificate appears in the secret section. In my case, I want the firewall enabled and still be able to use the certificate from the KV.